# Matlab how to save a modified image from axes

Tags: matlab

this is what i have so far
as you can see if i use save as i am using right now then i am saving the original image how would i save a modified image after applying one of the filters like black and white.

```
function varargout = testme(varargin)
% TESTME MATLAB code for testme.fig
%      TESTME, by itself, creates a new TESTME or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = TESTME returns the handle to a new TESTME or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      TESTME('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in TESTME.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      TESTME('Property','Value',...) creates a new TESTME or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before testme_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to testme_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help testme

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 13-Oct-2014 13:17:45

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @testme_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @testme_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before testme is made visible.
function testme_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to testme (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for testme

handles.fileLoaded = 0;
handles.fileLoaded2 = 0;


%-----------------------------------------------------------------------
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes testme wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = testme_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on button press in loadbutton.
function loadbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to loadbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im im2
[path,user_cance]=imgetfile();
if user_cance
    msgbox(sprintf('Error'),'Error','Error');
    return
end
im=imread(path);

im=im2double(im); %converts to double
im2=im; %for backup process :)
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(im);
axes(handles.axes2);

hist(im);















%-----------------------------------------------------------------------

% --- Executes on button press in resetbutton.
function resetbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to resetbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im2
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(im2);
axes(handles.axes2);

hist(im2);

% --- Executes on button press in negativebutton.
function negativebutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to negativebutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im
imblack=im;
imblack=1-im;
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(imblack);
axes(handles.axes2);

hist(imblack);


% --- Executes on button press in greybutton.
function greybutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to greybutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
global im
imgray=(im(:,:,1)+im(:,:,2)+im(:,:,2))/3;
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(imgray);
axes(handles.axes2);

hist(imgray);

% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

global im2
val=0.5*get(hObject,'Value')-0.5;
imbright=im2+val;
axes(handles.axes1);
imshow(imbright);
axes(handles.axes2);

hist(imbright);

% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end


% --- Executes on button press in savebutton.
function savebutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to savebutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[file,path]=uiputfile({'*.bmp','BMP'},'Save Image As');
f=getframe(handles.axes1); 
[x,map]=frame2im(f); 
imwrite(x,fullfile(path, file),'bmp');


% --- Executes on button press in black.
function black_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to black (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axes(handles.axes1);
global im
xb=im;
b=im2bw(xb);
imshow(b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but maybe a good way is to store the image (after applying a filter) in the figure's application data. You can do this with `guidata`.

After each filter you store the image;

```
% --- Executes on button press in black.
function black_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to black (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
axes(handles.axes1);
global im
xb=im;
b=im2bw(xb);
imshow(b);
% Store the image
handles.image = b;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then in your `savebutton_Callback`, simply refer to `handles.image`;